# Call a class method, when access to the property is a class that is not defined

Tags: php, oop

> __set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.
>
> __get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.
>
> __callStatic() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

How to call a class method, when access to the property is a class that is not defined?

```
class Conti{

    public function callback($variable){
        echo 'callback'.$variable;
    }
}   

echo Conti::not_defined_constant;
```

**Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'not_defined_constant'.**

Comment: What are you trying to do? I think what you need is to use static members.

Comment: your question sounds a bit controversial. can you tweak the wording? regarding example: you try to access an undefined class-constant, not to access the property. accessing static property would be: `Conti::$not_defined_property`. Anyway, there's no "[magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)" for that

Comment: JimiDini I know  ".... there's no magic method for that " .Maybe emulated?

Comment: I am tying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024997/how-to-call-callback-method-for-class