# How to call callback method for class?

Tags: php, oop

Help me please:

```
class xam{

       public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
            self::$name();
        }

        static protected function mycallback(){
            echo 'mycallback';
        }
    }

    function doIt($callback) { $callback(); }
```

I am trying:

```
doIt(xam::mycallback);
```

Error:

**Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'mycallback'**

I know one variant:

```
doIt(function(){xam::mycallback();});
```

But it may have an alternative ?
Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the callback as the string `"xam::mycallback"` or array `['xam', 'mycallback']`. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) describes all the options for specifying callables.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...

```
doIt('xam::mycallback');
```